# Can you have AutoMapper only map properties that match explicitly

Tags: c#, automapper

Is there a way to have AutoMapper only map properties that match explicitly? My Model has a property UserAccountId and also has a navigation property UserAccount that has an Id property, if the user posts UserAccountId, I want AutoMapper to map UserAccountId and leave UserAccount.Id null; I'd love to avoid using Ignore since that will prevent me from explicitly posting UserAccount.Id as well. I can't find any information on controlling AutoMapper's name matching strategy...

```
public class Role {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int UserAccountId {get; set;}
  public UserAccount UserAccount {get; set;}
  ...     
}

public class UserAccount {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  ...    
}

public class RoleViewModel {
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int UserAccountId {get; set;}
}

public ActionResult AddRole(RoleViewModel viewModel) {
  var model = GetModel(viewModel.Id);
  Mapper.Map(viewModel, model); 
  //Do not infer and map UserAccount.Id
}
```

Comment: What does GetModel do? What class does it return? Seems like those two lines can be condensed a bit.

Comment: The easy way is to rename things, but it can be [done](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/pull/922/files).

Comment: GetModel just hides the EntityFramework code for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

Don’t use AutoMapper for this case. It wasn’t built to support this type of scenario.

Or use ForPath(...).Ignore, but I just wouldn’t use my library for this scenario.